# Implementation of last comment and comments count SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, api

**Description**

I am developing an app which has Posts in it and for each post users can comment and like.
I am running a PG db on the server side and the data is structured in three different tables: post, post_comments (with ref to post), post_likes (with ref to post).

In the feed of the app I want to display all the posts with the comments count, last comment, number of likes and the last user that liked the post.

I was wondering what is the best approach to create the API calls, and currently have two ideas in mind:

**First Idea**

Make one large request using a query with multiple joins and parse the query accordingly.

The down side that I see in this approach is that the query will be very heavy which will affect the load time of the users feed as it will have to run over post_comments, post_likes, etc and count all the rows and then retrieve also the last rows.

**Second Idea**

Add an extra table which I will call post_meta that will store those exact parameters I need and update them when needed.

This approach will make the retrieve query much lighter and faster (faster loading time), but will increase the adding & updating time of comments and likes.

Was wondering if someone could give me some insights about the preferred way to tackle this problem.

Thanks

Comment: I don't see a clear problem statement, or if there be one, you didn't make it come across easily.  It might help if you show us some data, and then describe what your conundrum is with storing it.

Comment: I am considering two ways to implement my feed API call. I was wondering what is the best approach to withdraw the data from db and send it in the API call.